# Shift+Delete macOS equivalent?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, search, history

So, the particular Shift+Delete that I'm referring to is on a website like Reddit or any website with a search bar, on Windows, one can delete past searches by selecting an item and press the shift and delete (not backspace) and remove it.

I've searched on Google, Bing, and here, and all I was able to find was using Shift+Delete to permanently delete a file.

The only solution I came across was going into advanced settings and clearing all my browser history and cookies from the beginning of time, which is not something that I want to do. I just want to remove specific individual searches from the search bar, but not from my Chrome history.

I hope I was clear enough. Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome - try Fn + Shift + Delete or Ctrl + Fn + Shift + Delete.

Comment: Thank you so much. Both of them worked actually, and I didn't think about searching it with those words.